# Pass a react value into a JS Alert

Tags: reactjs

Im attempting to learn a little bit of react and struggling with this simple concept. I know its just a syntax thing that I'm unfamiliar with but I just can't get it down.

Im attempting to create a tic tac toe game, where each square has a value. When the square is clicked, it should pop up an alert box that shows "You've clicked box {Box Number}". I cannot figure out how to pass the value to the alert function.

```
class Square extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <button className="square" onClick={function() {alert("Youve clicked box " + this.props.value);}}>
        {this.props.value}
      </button>
    );
  }
}

class Board extends React.Component {
  renderSquare(i) {
    return <Square value={i} />;
  }

  render() {
    const status = 'Next player: X';

    return (
      <div>
        <div className="status">{status}</div>
        <div className="board-row">
          {this.renderSquare(0)}
          {this.renderSquare(1)}
          {this.renderSquare(2)}
        </div>
        <div className="board-row">
          {this.renderSquare(3)}
          {this.renderSquare(4)}
          {this.renderSquare(5)}
        </div>
        <div className="board-row">
          {this.renderSquare(6)}
          {this.renderSquare(7)}
          {this.renderSquare(8)}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Game extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="game">
        <div className="game-board">
          <Board />
        </div>
        <div className="game-info">
          <div>{/* status */}</div>
          <ol>{/* TODO */}</ol>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// ========================================

ReactDOM.render(
  <Game />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: what's happening right now when you click? does the alert show up?

Comment: Throws an error no matter which way I put the "this.props.value" in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your code and based on your comment, the issue is that you're trying to access the `props` attribute of an object (`this`) that doesn't have the `props` attribute.

One way you can do this is to use an arrow function.

```
<button onClick={() => { alert(`Something ${this.props.value}`); }>Click Me</button>
```

Another way is to bind the function.

```
class Box extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
   super(props)
   this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this)
  }

  onClick() {
    alert()
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.onClick}>Click Me</button>
    )
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you can directly use an arrow function inside your class so you don't have to bind if you don't want to define one in the render function.

```
class Box extends React.Component {
  onClick = () => {
    alert()
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.onClick}>Click Me</button>
    )
  }
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/1wfyq68r/

Comment: Perfect. I was on the right track by attempting to pass in the object of the "this" I was trying to use in further attempts after the post. Thanks much!!!

Answer (score 1):

You're re-binding the context of `this` by using a function declaration in your onClick. When you refer to `this` inside of that function, you're now referring to the context of that *function*, not the `Square` class (where `this.props` would reside).

Any easy fix is to use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) instead–it does not rebind the context of `this`.

```
 <button
    className="square"
    onClick={() => alert("Youve clicked box " + this.props.value)}
  >
  {this.props.value}
 </button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the context of the click handler function so it references the correct `this`. This can be done by either

1. Using an arrow function

```
() => alert("Youve clicked box " + this.props.value)
```

2. Explicitly binding

```
function() {
  alert("Youve clicked box " + this.props.value);
}.bind(this)
```

A useful resource as to why this is required [here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/this-is-why-we-need-to-bind-event-handlers-in-class-components-in-react-f7ea1a6f93eb/)